# sharepoint 2007 list datasheet view set fields background color

Tags: 2007

I have a list datasheet view in MOSS 2007. I have a requirement to set the background color to green for a set of fields. There is no conditions involved. whenever users select this view, they are able to see the background color for the set of few fields.

Please let me know the pointers to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have the option to modify the look and feel of the Cells in the datasheet view as this is essentially a cut down version of excel. You could possibly modify the standard view using CSS to get the effect you want.

Hope this helps.

S

Comment: CSS is not enough for standard list view, you should use XSLT transformation (this is default mechanism for list view rendering).

Comment: @Alexander XSLT is not the default for list rendering in SP 2007 (the question) or SP 2013. CSS should work just fine.

Comment: @Christophe, the CSS classes are the same for all list views. If you change in one place you will see the changes in other. I'm wrong? For modifying list view you should use CAML for SP2003, XSL for SP 2007 and 2010, new client rendering templates for SP2013. Could you provide links for default templates if XSL is not use for this purpose in SP2007?

Comment: @Alexander just open a SP 2007 list view in SharePoint Designer and you'll see there's no XSLT. Do the same with SP 2010 and you'll find the XSLT. As for CSS, of course you need to target specific views, not apply your CSS rules to the whole page.

Comment: @Christophe, May be you are right, I have not worked with SP2007 since SP2010 was realised. But in SP2007 you can use this method, see [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300164%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [this video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af1e9a1a-b9ec-41fd-a37e-bdf4c1832245?cid=sdc&from=msdnlibsdc&VideoID=c1447ff5-0a58-4243-83a6-7c8a68396163).

Comment: @Alexander absolutely, I was just pointing out that it's not the default.